# Passing bash array to python function

Tags: bash, python

I need to send an array which is defined in bash script to python script which modifies and return that array. Which then needs to get assigned to bash array again. Moreover like bash has to maintain the array value and python has to modify value.

**Bash script:**

```bsh
   arr=(0)
   ret=`python -c 'from pyscript import fun;print fun(arr)'`
   arr = ${ret[@]}  # assign returned array from python script to bash array
```

**Python script:**

```py
def fun(arr):
   arr.append(1)
   return arr
```

Help me out of this.

Comment: the last sentence `Moreover like bash has to maintain the array value and python has to modify value.` is going to be a problem for you.  It is impossible for a child-process (e.g. your python script) to directly modify the environment of a parent process (e.g. your bash script)...at best, it can return the modified value as a result to the parent, and then then parent can use the result to change an env var.

Comment: @cas Yeah, python script will give the modified array in return. I've mentioned that already `python script which modifies and return that array`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
arr=(0)
ret="$(python -c 'from pyscript import fun;print fun(arr)' "${arr[@]}")"
mapfile -t arr <<<"$ret" # assign returned array from python script to bash array
```

It assumes that your python script takes its input from the command line and stores each argument into the python array `arr`.   Unless your python script is just a small fragment of a larger program, your code doesn't do this.  I'll leave that up to you.  This answer is focused on how bash can pass the array to python and then modify it based on the data returned from the python script.

The python script needs to print the array to stdout, with each element separated by a line-feed.

@xenoid's suggestion is to use:

```
ret="$(python -c 'import sys;from pyscript import fun;print fun(sys.argv[1:])' "${arr[@]}")"
```

Comment: More like `ret=$(python -c 'import sys;from pyscript import fun;print fun(sys.argv[1:])' "${arr[@]}")` I think.

Comment: @xenoid cool, thanks.  i dodn't want to have to look up basic argv processing in python.  i use perl a LOT more often than python.

Comment: Thanks @xenoid and @cas. I've tried to pass the array by value instead of command line arg. More like, ```ret=`python -c 'from pyscript import fun; arr=['${arr[@]}']; print fun(arr)'` ``` This worked for me.

Comment: _" If any of the array elements contain whitespace, they need to be quoted."_ -- that won't work, quotes aren't processed after variable expansion...

Comment: @ilkkachu oops, you're right.  looks like the way to set the array is for the python script to output LF separated elements, and then use `mapfile` to read the array back into `arr`.  i'll edit my answer.

Comment: @cas, or print NUL-separated values, `mapfile -d ''` seems to work with those, though that's probably just as documented as `read -d ''`

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah, NUL works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to Python adding it as arguments and use `sys.argv[1:]` inside python to read it.

Giving back to `bash` is a bit tricky when your values may contain spaces or newlines, but you could use newline-separated output of python together with `readline`.

```
arr=(0)
readarray -t arr < <(python -c '
import sys
arr=sys.argv[1:]
arr.append(1)
arr.append("a b")
for a in arr:
  print(a)
' "${arr[@]}")
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Output:

```
0
1
a b
```